# Reverse Transcription

Tags: python, genetic

The objective is get the Coding sequence of the mRNA given the complete mRNA sequence and the Amino acid sequence. Then put all of this in codon format.
I feel that I have finding the possible list codons figured out. I am just not sure how to systematically match with the given mRNA sequence. So here is what I have so far.

```
xAA = 'MDFFASGLPLVTEETPSGEAGSEEDDEVVAMIKELLDTRIRPTVQEDGGDVIYKGFEDGIVQLKLQGSCTSCPSSIITLKNGIQNMLQFYIPEVEGVEQVMDDESDEKEANSP'

xmRNA = 'GUUCCCCGGCCUCUCUUGGUCAGGGUGACGCAGUAGCCUGCAAACCUCGGCGCGUAGGCCACCGCACUUAUCCGCAGCAGGACCGCCCGCAGCCGGUAGGGUGGGCUCUUCCCAGUGCCCGCCCAGCUACCGGCCAGCCUGCGGCUGCGCAGAUCUUUCGUGGUUCUGUCAGGGAGACCCUUAGGCACUCCGGACUAAGAUGGCGGCGACGGCCAGGCGGGGCUGGGGAGCUGCGGCUGUUGCCGCCGGGCUGCGCAGGCGGUUCUGUCAUAUGUUGAAGAAUCCAUACACCAUUAAGAAACAGCCUCUGCAUCAGUUUGUACAAAGACCACUUUUCCCACUACCUGCAGCCUUUUAUCACCCAGGCAGUUAUUUAGGAUUGAAGGAGUAAAAAGUGUCUUCUUUGGACCAGAUUUCAUCACUGUCACAAAGGAAAAUGAAGAAUUAGACUGGAAUUUACUGAAACCAGAUAUUUAUGCAACAAUCAUGGACUUCUUUGCAUCUGGCUUACCCCUGGUUACUGAGGAAACACCUUCAGGAGAAGCAGGAUCUGAAGAAGAUGAUGAAGUUGUGGCAAUGAUUAAGGAAUUGUUAGAUACUAGAAUACGGCCAACUGUGCAGGAAGAUGGAGGGGAUGUAAUCUACAAAGGCUUUGAAGAUGGCAUUGUACAGCUGAAACUCCAGGGUUCUUGUACCAGCUGCCCUAGUUCAAUCAUUACUCUGAAAAAUGGAAUUCAGAACAUGCUGCAGUUUUAUAUUCCGGAGGUAGAAGGCGUAGAACAGGUUAUGGAUGAUGAAUCAGAUGAAAAAGAAGCAAACUCACCUUAAAAUAAUCUGGAUUUUCUUUGGGCAUAACAGUCAGACUUGUUGAUAAUAUAUAUCAAGUUUUUAUUAUUAAUAUGCUGAGGAACUUGAAGAUUAAUAAAAUAUGCUCUUCAGAGAAUGAUAUAUAAAA'

d = {'mRNA': ['UUU','UUC','UUA','UUG','UCU','UCC','UCA','UCG','UAU','UAC','UAA','UAG','UGU','UGC','UGA','UGG','CUU','CUC','CUA','CUG','CCU','CCC','CCA','CCG','CAU','CAC','CAA','CAG','CGU','CGC','CGA','CGG','AUU','AUC','AUA','AUG','ACU','ACC','ACA','ACG','AAU','AAC','AAA','AAG','AGU','AGC','AGA','AGG','GUU','GUC','GUA','GUG','GCU','GCC','GCA','GCG','GAU','GAC','GAA','GAG','GGU','GGC','GGA','GGG'], 'AA': ['F','F','L','L','S','S','S','S','Y','Y','_','_','C','C','_','W','L','L','L','L','P','P','P','P','H','H','Q','Q','R','R','R','R','I','I','M','M','T','T','T','T','N','N','K','K','S','S','R','R','V','V','V','V','A','A','A','A','D','D','E','E','G','G','G','G']}

AA= pandas.DataFrame(data=d)
for i in xAA:
    codons = list(AA.mRNA.loc[AA['AA'] == i])
    print codons
```

This is the output:

```
['AUA', 'AUG']
['GAU', 'GAC']
['UUU', 'UUC']
['UUU', 'UUC']
['GCU', 'GCC', 'GCA', 'GCG']
['UCU', 'UCC', 'UCA', 'UCG', 'AGU', 'AGC']
['GGU', 'GGC', 'GGA', 'GGG']
['UUA', 'UUG', 'CUU', 'CUC', 'CUA', 'CUG']
['CCU', 'CCC', 'CCA', 'CCG']
['UUA', 'UUG', 'CUU', 'CUC', 'CUA', 'CUG']
['GUU', 'GUC', 'GUA', 'GUG']
['ACU', 'ACC', 'ACA', 'ACG']
['GAA', 'GAG']
['GAA', 'GAG']
['ACU', 'ACC', 'ACA', 'ACG']
['CCU', 'CCC', 'CCA', 'CCG']
['UCU', 'UCC', 'UCA', 'UCG', 'AGU', 'AGC']
['GGU', 'GGC', 'GGA', 'GGG']
['GAA', 'GAG']
['GCU', 'GCC', 'GCA', 'GCG']
['GGU', 'GGC', 'GGA', 'GGG']
['UCU', 'UCC', 'UCA', 'UCG', 'AGU', 'AGC']
['GAA', 'GAG']
['GAA', 'GAG']
['GAU', 'GAC']
['GAU', 'GAC']
['GAA', 'GAG']
['GUU', 'GUC', 'GUA', 'GUG']
['GUU', 'GUC', 'GUA', 'GUG']
['GCU', 'GCC', 'GCA', 'GCG']
['AUA', 'AUG']
['AUU', 'AUC']
['AAA', 'AAG']
['GAA', 'GAG']
['UUA', 'UUG', 'CUU', 'CUC', 'CUA', 'CUG']
['UUA', 'UUG', 'CUU', 'CUC', 'CUA', 'CUG']
['GAU', 'GAC']
['ACU', 'ACC', 'ACA', 'ACG']
['CGU', 'CGC', 'CGA', 'CGG', 'AGA', 'AGG']
['AUU', 'AUC']
['CGU', 'CGC', 'CGA', 'CGG', 'AGA', 'AGG']
['CCU', 'CCC', 'CCA', 'CCG']
['ACU', 'ACC', 'ACA', 'ACG']
['GUU', 'GUC', 'GUA', 'GUG']
['CAA', 'CAG']
['GAA', 'GAG']
['GAU', 'GAC']
['GGU', 'GGC', 'GGA', 'GGG']
['GGU', 'GGC', 'GGA', 'GGG']
['GAU', 'GAC']
['GUU', 'GUC', 'GUA', 'GUG']
['AUU', 'AUC']
['UAU', 'UAC']
['AAA', 'AAG']
['GGU', 'GGC', 'GGA', 'GGG']
['UUU', 'UUC']
['GAA', 'GAG']
['GAU', 'GAC']
['GGU', 'GGC', 'GGA', 'GGG']
['AUU', 'AUC']
['GUU', 'GUC', 'GUA', 'GUG']
['CAA', 'CAG']
['UUA', 'UUG', 'CUU', 'CUC', 'CUA', 'CUG']
['AAA', 'AAG']
['UUA', 'UUG', 'CUU', 'CUC', 'CUA', 'CUG']
['CAA', 'CAG']
['GGU', 'GGC', 'GGA', 'GGG']
['UCU', 'UCC', 'UCA', 'UCG', 'AGU', 'AGC']
['UGU', 'UGC']
['ACU', 'ACC', 'ACA', 'ACG']
['UCU', 'UCC', 'UCA', 'UCG', 'AGU', 'AGC']
['UGU', 'UGC']
['CCU', 'CCC', 'CCA', 'CCG']
['UCU', 'UCC', 'UCA', 'UCG', 'AGU', 'AGC']
['UCU', 'UCC', 'UCA', 'UCG', 'AGU', 'AGC']
['AUU', 'AUC']
['AUU', 'AUC']
['ACU', 'ACC', 'ACA', 'ACG']
['UUA', 'UUG', 'CUU', 'CUC', 'CUA', 'CUG']
['AAA', 'AAG']
['AAU', 'AAC']
['GGU', 'GGC', 'GGA', 'GGG']
['AUU', 'AUC']
['CAA', 'CAG']
['AAU', 'AAC']
['AUA', 'AUG']
['UUA', 'UUG', 'CUU', 'CUC', 'CUA', 'CUG']
['CAA', 'CAG']
['UUU', 'UUC']
['UAU', 'UAC']
['AUU', 'AUC']
['CCU', 'CCC', 'CCA', 'CCG']
['GAA', 'GAG']
['GUU', 'GUC', 'GUA', 'GUG']
['GAA', 'GAG']
['GGU', 'GGC', 'GGA', 'GGG']
['GUU', 'GUC', 'GUA', 'GUG']
['GAA', 'GAG']
['CAA', 'CAG']
['GUU', 'GUC', 'GUA', 'GUG']
['AUA', 'AUG']
['GAU', 'GAC']
['GAU', 'GAC']
['GAA', 'GAG']
['UCU', 'UCC', 'UCA', 'UCG', 'AGU', 'AGC']
['GAU', 'GAC']
['GAA', 'GAG']
['AAA', 'AAG']
['GAA', 'GAG']
['GCU', 'GCC', 'GCA', 'GCG']
['AAU', 'AAC']
['UCU', 'UCC', 'UCA', 'UCG', 'AGU', 'AGC']
['CCU', 'CCC', 'CCA', 'CCG']
```

If I add the for c loop shown here I get

```
codingseq = ""
for i in xAA:
    codons = list(AA.mRNA.loc[AA['AA'] == i])
    for c in codons:
        xmRNA.find(c)
        codingseq+= c
```

This gives every combination is there a way to a compartive analysis to find which of these is most like full mRNA seq?

```
AUAAUG
AUAAUGGAUGAC
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUC
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUC
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGC
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGC
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGC
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGAAGAG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGAAGAGGAAGAG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGAAGAGGAAGAGGAUGAC
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGAAGAGGAAGAGGAUGACGAUGAC
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGAAGAGGAAGAGGAUGACGAUGACGAAGAG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGAAGAGGAAGAGGAUGACGAUGACGAAGAGGUUGUCGUAGUG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGAAGAGGAAGAGGAUGACGAUGACGAAGAGGUUGUCGUAGUGGUUGUCGUAGUG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGAAGAGGAAGAGGAUGACGAUGACGAAGAGGUUGUCGUAGUGGUUGUCGUAGUGGCUGCCGCAGCG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGAAGAGGAAGAGGAUGACGAUGACGAAGAGGUUGUCGUAGUGGUUGUCGUAGUGGCUGCCGCAGCGAUAAUG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGAAGAGGAAGAGGAUGACGAUGACGAAGAGGUUGUCGUAGUGGUUGUCGUAGUGGCUGCCGCAGCGAUAAUGAUUAUC
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGAAGAGGAAGAGGAUGACGAUGACGAAGAGGUUGUCGUAGUGGUUGUCGUAGUGGCUGCCGCAGCGAUAAUGAUUAUCAAAAAG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGAAGAGGAAGAGGAUGACGAUGACGAAGAGGUUGUCGUAGUGGUUGUCGUAGUGGCUGCCGCAGCGAUAAUGAUUAUCAAAAAGGAAGAG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGAAGAGGAAGAGGAUGACGAUGACGAAGAGGUUGUCGUAGUGGUUGUCGUAGUGGCUGCCGCAGCGAUAAUGAUUAUCAAAAAGGAAGAGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGAAGAGGAAGAGGAUGACGAUGACGAAGAGGUUGUCGUAGUGGUUGUCGUAGUGGCUGCCGCAGCGAUAAUGAUUAUCAAAAAGGAAGAGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGAAGAGGAAGAGGAUGACGAUGACGAAGAGGUUGUCGUAGUGGUUGUCGUAGUGGCUGCCGCAGCGAUAAUGAUUAUCAAAAAGGAAGAGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGAUGAC
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGAAGAGGAAGAGGAUGACGAUGACGAAGAGGUUGUCGUAGUGGUUGUCGUAGUGGCUGCCGCAGCGAUAAUGAUUAUCAAAAAGGAAGAGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGAUGACACUACCACAACG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGAAGAGGAAGAGGAUGACGAUGACGAAGAGGUUGUCGUAGUGGUUGUCGUAGUGGCUGCCGCAGCGAUAAUGAUUAUCAAAAAGGAAGAGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGAUGACACUACCACAACGCGUCGCCGACGGAGAAGG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGAAGAGGAAGAGGAUGACGAUGACGAAGAGGUUGUCGUAGUGGUUGUCGUAGUGGCUGCCGCAGCGAUAAUGAUUAUCAAAAAGGAAGAGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGAUGACACUACCACAACGCGUCGCCGACGGAGAAGGAUUAUC
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGAAGAGGAAGAGGAUGACGAUGACGAAGAGGUUGUCGUAGUGGUUGUCGUAGUGGCUGCCGCAGCGAUAAUGAUUAUCAAAAAGGAAGAGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGAUGACACUACCACAACGCGUCGCCGACGGAGAAGGAUUAUCCGUCGCCGACGGAGAAGG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGAAGAGGAAGAGGAUGACGAUGACGAAGAGGUUGUCGUAGUGGUUGUCGUAGUGGCUGCCGCAGCGAUAAUGAUUAUCAAAAAGGAAGAGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGAUGACACUACCACAACGCGUCGCCGACGGAGAAGGAUUAUCCGUCGCCGACGGAGAAGGCCUCCCCCACCG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGAAGAGGAAGAGGAUGACGAUGACGAAGAGGUUGUCGUAGUGGUUGUCGUAGUGGCUGCCGCAGCGAUAAUGAUUAUCAAAAAGGAAGAGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGAUGACACUACCACAACGCGUCGCCGACGGAGAAGGAUUAUCCGUCGCCGACGGAGAAGGCCUCCCCCACCGACUACCACAACG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGAAGAGGAAGAGGAUGACGAUGACGAAGAGGUUGUCGUAGUGGUUGUCGUAGUGGCUGCCGCAGCGAUAAUGAUUAUCAAAAAGGAAGAGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGAUGACACUACCACAACGCGUCGCCGACGGAGAAGGAUUAUCCGUCGCCGACGGAGAAGGCCUCCCCCACCGACUACCACAACGGUUGUCGUAGUG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGAAGAGGAAGAGGAUGACGAUGACGAAGAGGUUGUCGUAGUGGUUGUCGUAGUGGCUGCCGCAGCGAUAAUGAUUAUCAAAAAGGAAGAGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGAUGACACUACCACAACGCGUCGCCGACGGAGAAGGAUUAUCCGUCGCCGACGGAGAAGGCCUCCCCCACCGACUACCACAACGGUUGUCGUAGUGCAACAG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGAAGAGGAAGAGGAUGACGAUGACGAAGAGGUUGUCGUAGUGGUUGUCGUAGUGGCUGCCGCAGCGAUAAUGAUUAUCAAAAAGGAAGAGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGAUGACACUACCACAACGCGUCGCCGACGGAGAAGGAUUAUCCGUCGCCGACGGAGAAGGCCUCCCCCACCGACUACCACAACGGUUGUCGUAGUGCAACAGGAAGAG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGAAGAGGAAGAGGAUGACGAUGACGAAGAGGUUGUCGUAGUGGUUGUCGUAGUGGCUGCCGCAGCGAUAAUGAUUAUCAAAAAGGAAGAGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGAUGACACUACCACAACGCGUCGCCGACGGAGAAGGAUUAUCCGUCGCCGACGGAGAAGGCCUCCCCCACCGACUACCACAACGGUUGUCGUAGUGCAACAGGAAGAGGAUGAC
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGAAGAGGAAGAGGAUGACGAUGACGAAGAGGUUGUCGUAGUGGUUGUCGUAGUGGCUGCCGCAGCGAUAAUGAUUAUCAAAAAGGAAGAGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGAUGACACUACCACAACGCGUCGCCGACGGAGAAGGAUUAUCCGUCGCCGACGGAGAAGGCCUCCCCCACCGACUACCACAACGGUUGUCGUAGUGCAACAGGAAGAGGAUGACGGUGGCGGAGGG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGAAGAGGAAGAGGAUGACGAUGACGAAGAGGUUGUCGUAGUGGUUGUCGUAGUGGCUGCCGCAGCGAUAAUGAUUAUCAAAAAGGAAGAGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGAUGACACUACCACAACGCGUCGCCGACGGAGAAGGAUUAUCCGUCGCCGACGGAGAAGGCCUCCCCCACCGACUACCACAACGGUUGUCGUAGUGCAACAGGAAGAGGAUGACGGUGGCGGAGGGGGUGGCGGAGGG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGAAGAGGAAGAGGAUGACGAUGACGAAGAGGUUGUCGUAGUGGUUGUCGUAGUGGCUGCCGCAGCGAUAAUGAUUAUCAAAAAGGAAGAGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGAUGACACUACCACAACGCGUCGCCGACGGAGAAGGAUUAUCCGUCGCCGACGGAGAAGGCCUCCCCCACCGACUACCACAACGGUUGUCGUAGUGCAACAGGAAGAGGAUGACGGUGGCGGAGGGGGUGGCGGAGGGGAUGAC
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGAAGAGGAAGAGGAUGACGAUGACGAAGAGGUUGUCGUAGUGGUUGUCGUAGUGGCUGCCGCAGCGAUAAUGAUUAUCAAAAAGGAAGAGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGAUGACACUACCACAACGCGUCGCCGACGGAGAAGGAUUAUCCGUCGCCGACGGAGAAGGCCUCCCCCACCGACUACCACAACGGUUGUCGUAGUGCAACAGGAAGAGGAUGACGGUGGCGGAGGGGGUGGCGGAGGGGAUGACGUUGUCGUAGUG
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGAAGAGGAAGAGGAUGACGAUGACGAAGAGGUUGUCGUAGUGGUUGUCGUAGUGGCUGCCGCAGCGAUAAUGAUUAUCAAAAAGGAAGAGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGAUGACACUACCACAACGCGUCGCCGACGGAGAAGGAUUAUCCGUCGCCGACGGAGAAGGCCUCCCCCACCGACUACCACAACGGUUGUCGUAGUGCAACAGGAAGAGGAUGACGGUGGCGGAGGGGGUGGCGGAGGGGAUGACGUUGUCGUAGUGAUUAUC
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGAAGAGGAAGAGGAUGACGAUGACGAAGAGGUUGUCGUAGUGGUUGUCGUAGUGGCUGCCGCAGCGAUAAUGAUUAUCAAAAAGGAAGAGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGAUGACACUACCACAACGCGUCGCCGACGGAGAAGGAUUAUCCGUCGCCGACGGAGAAGGCCUCCCCCACCGACUACCACAACGGUUGUCGUAGUGCAACAGGAAGAGGAUGACGGUGGCGGAGGGGGUGGCGGAGGGGAUGACGUUGUCGUAGUGAUUAUCUAUUAC
AUAAUGGAUGACUUUUUCUUUUUCGCUGCCGCAGCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGCCUCCCCCACCGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGUUGUCGUAGUGACUACCACAACGGAAGAGGAAGAGACUACCACAACGCCUCCCCCACCGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGGUGGCGGAGGGGAAGAGGCUGCCGCAGCGGGUGGCGGAGGGUCUUCCUCAUCGAGUAGCGAAGAGGAAGAGGAUGACGAUGACGAAGAGGUUGUCGUAGUGGUUGUCGUAGUGGCUGCCGCAGCGAUAAUGAUUAUCAAAAAGGAAGAGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGUUAUUGCUUCUCCUACUGGAUGACACUACCACAACGCGUCGCCGACGGAGAAGGAUUAUCCGUCGCCGACGGAGAAGGCCUCCCCCACCGACUACCACAACGGUUGUCGUAGUGCAACAGGAAGAGGAUGACGGUGGCGGAGGGGGUGGCGGAGGGGAUGACGUUGUCGUAGUGAUUAUCUAUUACAAAAAG
```

Please note not all results shown as it exceeds the character limit.
Any help on this would be awesome!

Comment: The goal is not very clear. My guess is that d['mRNA'] and d['AA'] (if taken in pairs) represent the mapping between codons and AAs (with possible multiple codons encoding the same AA). The relationship between xmRNA and xAA is not clear - is it that somewhere in xmRNA there is a sequence of codons that is known to match the entire xAA? (and you just need to find out where it is).

Comment: Does codon ordering matter?  Is AUAAUG GAUGAC valid, but GAUGAC AUAAUG not valid?

Comment: @LeoK xAA is the Amino acid sequence that is created when xmRNA is translated (that process is biological) however that process has been mapped meaning that when we see a mRNA sequence we can break them up into groups of the 3 (codons) and then translate them to protein. However in some cases there can be multiple codons for one AA (amino acid). The data frame and the for loop looks at xmRNA and finds all of those possibilities. For example  row 1 in the first output show AUA and AUG, both of these make a M (Methionine)  but it is important to know which one is the one actually used

Comment: @Saedeas yes, order matters other wise you are making an entirely different protein

Comment: Okay, one last question.  Do earlier strings have to appear for later strings to be relevant?  Am I checking every possible subsequence of the output or does AUAAUG always have to be the start? I.E. is it meaningful if I find a sequence of codons that appear at the end of your output (say the last 20 in a row or something similar)?

Comment: @Saedeas I forgot to clarify this, it will always start with an AUG. and it will end with one of these UAA, UAG, UGA does that answer your question?

Comment: @jcruzer: I know how mRNA transcription to proteins works. I also know that there's more than one codon for each amino acid. The possibilities are listed in your d[] data (up to 4 codons for some AAs, with some codons not matching any AA, these are used as 'frames markers' in DNA/RNA). I can't figure out what is it that you are looking for, though. BTW: I checked that the (full-length) xAA sequence is NOT coded for anywhere in xmRNA. A sequence that codes for the first 39 AAs in xAA can be found at position 487 in xmRNA, that's the longest one I found (looking for xAA[0:x] only).

Comment: @Saedeas I am looking for the coding sequence when given the full mRNA seq, and the Amino acid sequence for reference. The xmRNA does code for AA given however the entire mRNA sequence is not used, which is common. you can use this translate tool to confirm. I[link] (https://web.expasy.org/cgi-bin/translate/dna_aa)

Comment: @jcruzer: you have a data entry error in your code. The web.expasy.org site translates AUA to "I", your data translates it to "M", which is why my attempt to match the strings failed. After fixing this, the entire xAA string can be mapped to the xmDNA at position 487 exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finds a codon sequence in xmRNA tha matches xAA. NOTE the d["AA"] data was corrected at index 34 ("M" replaced with "I"), to match the translation used on the http://web.expasy.org/ site. I haven't used `pandas`, just plain Python. I just did this one as a simple test to try and find where xAA is found in xmRNA (and what codons are used). It should be fast enough even for very long sequences (even 100000 RNAs should be near-instant).

```
xAA = 'MDFFASGLPLVTEETPSGEAGSEEDDEVVAMIKELLDTRIRPTVQEDGGDVIYKGFEDGIVQLKLQGSCTSCPSSIITLKNGIQNMLQFYIPEVEGVEQVMDDESDEKEANSP'
xmRNA = 'GUUCCCCGGCCUCUCUUGGUCAGGGUGACGCAGUAGCCUGCAAACCUCGGCGCGUAGGCCACCGCACUUAUCCGCAGCAGGACCGCCCGCAGCCGGUAGGGUGGGCUCUUCCCAGUGCCCGCCCAGCUACCGGCCAGCCUGCGGCUGCGCAGAUCUUUCGUGGUUCUGUCAGGGAGACCCUUAGGCACUCCGGACUAAGAUGGCGGCGACGGCCAGGCGGGGCUGGGGAGCUGCGGCUGUUGCCGCCGGGCUGCGCAGGCGGUUCUGUCAUAUGUUGAAGAAUCCAUACACCAUUAAGAAACAGCCUCUGCAUCAGUUUGUACAAAGACCACUUUUCCCACUACCUGCAGCCUUUUAUCACCCAGGCAGUUAUUUAGGAUUGAAGGAGUAAAAAGUGUCUUCUUUGGACCAGAUUUCAUCACUGUCACAAAGGAAAAUGAAGAAUUAGACUGGAAUUUACUGAAACCAGAUAUUUAUGCAACAAUCAUGGACUUCUUUGCAUCUGGCUUACCCCUGGUUACUGAGGAAACACCUUCAGGAGAAGCAGGAUCUGAAGAAGAUGAUGAAGUUGUGGCAAUGAUUAAGGAAUUGUUAGAUACUAGAAUACGGCCAACUGUGCAGGAAGAUGGAGGGGAUGUAAUCUACAAAGGCUUUGAAGAUGGCAUUGUACAGCUGAAACUCCAGGGUUCUUGUACCAGCUGCCCUAGUUCAAUCAUUACUCUGAAAAAUGGAAUUCAGAACAUGCUGCAGUUUUAUAUUCCGGAGGUAGAAGGCGUAGAACAGGUUAUGGAUGAUGAAUCAGAUGAAAAAGAAGCAAACUCACCUUAAAAUAAUCUGGAUUUUCUUUGGGCAUAACAGUCAGACUUGUUGAUAAUAUAUAUCAAGUUUUUAUUAUUAAUAUGCUGAGGAACUUGAAGAUUAAUAAAAUAUGCUCUUCAGAGAAUGAUAUAUAAAA'

d = {'mRNA': ['UUU','UUC','UUA','UUG','UCU','UCC','UCA','UCG','UAU','UAC','UAA','UAG','UGU','UGC','UGA','UGG','CUU','CUC','CUA','CUG','CCU','CCC','CCA','CCG','CAU','CAC','CAA','CAG','CGU','CGC','CGA','CGG','AUU','AUC','AUA','AUG','ACU','ACC','ACA','ACG','AAU','AAC','AAA','AAG','AGU','AGC','AGA','AGG','GUU','GUC','GUA','GUG','GCU','GCC','GCA','GCG','GAU','GAC','GAA','GAG','GGU','GGC','GGA','GGG'],
       'AA': ['F',  'F',  'L',  'L',  'S',  'S',  'S',  'S',  'Y',  'Y',  '_',  '_',  'C',  'C',  '_','W','L','L','L','L','P','P','P','P','H','H','Q','Q','R','R','R','R','I','I',   'I'   ,'M','T','T','T','T','N','N','K','K','S','S','R','R','V','V','V','V','A','A','A','A','D','D','E','E','G','G','G','G']}

r2a = { d['mRNA'][i] : d['AA'][i] for i in range(len(d['AA'])) }

s=0
found = False
for s in (0,1,2):
    # t3 = codon sequence starting from s
    t = list(xmRNA[s:])
    t3 = [ t[i]+t[i+1]+t[i+2] for i in range(0,len(t)-2,3) ]
    # transcribe to AAs
    aa = [ r2a[i] for i in t3 ]
    aa = ''.join(aa)
    print (aa)
    try:
        idx = aa.index(xAA)
    except ValueError:
        continue

    # found it
    pos = idx*3 + s
    t3 = t3[idx:idx+len(xAA)]
    found = True
    break

if found:
    print ("found in frame {} at {} (pos={})".format(s+1, idx, pos))
    print ("codons: " + repr(t3))
else:
    print ("Not found")
```

Comment: You can construct r2a shorter with: `r2a = dict(zip(d['mRNA'],d['AA']))`

Comment: @rioV8: actually, I'd go farther and place the output repr(zip(d['mRNA'],d['AA'])) in the source as the mapping data (tuples of (codon, AA)), instead of the two arrays. This would make it clearer what maps to what.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly compact solution.  You don't have any clashes when you create a reverse dictionary, so you can do something like so:

```
codon_dict = {'F': ('UUU', 'UUC'),
              'L': ('UUA', 'UUG', 'CUU', 'CUC', 'CUA', 'CUG'),
              'S': ('UCU', 'UCC', 'UCA', 'UCG', 'AGU', 'AGC'),
              'Y': ('UAU', 'UAC'),
              '_': ('UAA', 'UAG', 'UGA'),
              'C': ('UGU', 'UGC'),
              'W': ('UGG',),
              'P': ('CCU', 'CCC', 'CCA', 'CCG'),
              'H': ('CAU', 'CAC'),
              'Q': ('CAA', 'CAG'),
              'R': ('CGU', 'CGC', 'CGA', 'CGG', 'AGA', 'AGG'),
              'I': ('AUU', 'AUC', 'AUA'),
              'M': ('AUG',),
              'T': ('ACU', 'ACC', 'ACA', 'ACG'),
              'N': ('AAU', 'AAC'),
              'K': ('AAA', 'AAG'),
              'V': ('GUU', 'GUC', 'GUA', 'GUG'),
              'A': ('GCU', 'GCC', 'GCA', 'GCG'),
              'D': ('GAU', 'GAC'),
              'E': ('GAA', 'GAG'),
              'G': ('GGU', 'GGC', 'GGA', 'GGG')
             }

rna_dict = {}
for k, v in codon_dict.items():
    for val in v:
        rna_dict[val] = k

xAA = 'MDFFASGLPLVTEETPSGEAGSEEDDEVVAMIKELLDTRIRPTVQEDGGDVIYKGFEDGIVQLKLQGSCTSCPSSIITLKNGIQNMLQFYIPEVEGVEQVMDDESDEKEANSP'
xmRNA = 'GUUCCCCGGCCUCUCUUGGUCAGGGUGACGCAGUAGCCUGCAAACCUCGGCGCGUAGGCCACCGCACUUAUCCGCAGCAGGACCGCCCGCAGCCGGUAGGGUGGGCUCUUCCCAGUGCCCGCCCAGCUACCGGCCAGCCUGCGGCUGCGCAGAUCUUUCGUGGUUCUGUCAGGGAGACCCUUAGGCACUCCGGACUAAGAUGGCGGCGACGGCCAGGCGGGGCUGGGGAGCUGCGGCUGUUGCCGCCGGGCUGCGCAGGCGGUUCUGUCAUAUGUUGAAGAAUCCAUACACCAUUAAGAAACAGCCUCUGCAUCAGUUUGUACAAAGACCACUUUUCCCACUACCUGCAGCCUUUUAUCACCCAGGCAGUUAUUUAGGAUUGAAGGAGUAAAAAGUGUCUUCUUUGGACCAGAUUUCAUCACUGUCACAAAGGAAAAUGAAGAAUUAGACUGGAAUUUACUGAAACCAGAUAUUUAUGCAACAAUCAUGGACUUCUUUGCAUCUGGCUUACCCCUGGUUACUGAGGAAACACCUUCAGGAGAAGCAGGAUCUGAAGAAGAUGAUGAAGUUGUGGCAAUGAUUAAGGAAUUGUUAGAUACUAGAAUACGGCCAACUGUGCAGGAAGAUGGAGGGGAUGUAAUCUACAAAGGCUUUGAAGAUGGCAUUGUACAGCUGAAACUCCAGGGUUCUUGUACCAGCUGCCCUAGUUCAAUCAUUACUCUGAAAAAUGGAAUUCAGAACAUGCUGCAGUUUUAUAUUCCGGAGGUAGAAGGCGUAGAACAGGUUAUGGAUGAUGAAUCAGAUGAAAAAGAAGCAAACUCACCUUAAAAUAAUCUGGAUUUUCUUUGGGCAUAACAGUCAGACUUGUUGAUAAUAUAUAUCAAGUUUUUAUUAUUAAUAUGCUGAGGAACUUGAAGAUUAAUAAAAUAUGCUCUUCAGAGAAUGAUAUAUAAAA'

mapped = [rna_dict[x] for x in [xmRNA[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(xmRNA)-1, 3)]]

xmRNA_index = "".join(mapped).find(xAA) * 3
print(xmRNA_index)
```

This returns 486, which is where the xAA codons are located.  It could be fleshed out further with bounds checks on the string and you could do combination matching of the substrings if you just wanted the closest matches (I would still do the reverse mapping and then search in that space though, it's faster), but yeah. I also don't know how common missing characters/triplets that don't map are, so it may need modification for those cases.